# Flask-Admin: How to get Model object attribute in ModelView?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

**Initial info:**

I have `Page` model in `SQLAlchemy`:

```
class Page(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128), default="", nullable=False, unique=True)
    main_image = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
```

It has `PageView` (`ModelView` from `Flask-Admin`) with `ImageUploadField` override:

```
class PageView(ModelView):

    form_extra_fields = {
        'main_image': form.ImageUploadField(
            'Main image',
            base_path=file_path,
            relative_path='product_images/{}/'.format(models.Page.url),
            thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True),
        )}

from app import models
```

**What I want:** to save images in a different subfolder for each page, using page url (like 'about' or 'samsung-galaxy-7') as subfolder name. Need it for custom duplicate action, so files with the same names don't overwrite each other.

**Main problem:** I can't get `Page` object attribute inside `PageView` to use it in path. I can get it inside some Flask-Admin methods, like `on_model_change`, so I can move/remove files manually after each model change, but it feels really unpythonic.

**Question**: So, is there any way to use object attribute inside `ModelView`? Smth like `__init__ super()` and so on is totally acceptable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `ImageUploadField.namegen` ([docs](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_form_upload/#flask_admin.form.upload.ImageUploadField)). I decided not to create subdirectories, but to add url prefix to all page images:

```
def add_url_to_name(obj, file_data):
    parts = op.splitext(file_data.filename)
    return '{}_{}{}'.format(obj.url, parts[0], parts[1])

form_extra_fields = {
    'main_image': form.ImageUploadField(
        'Main image',
        base_path=file_path,
        relative_path='product_images/',
        thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True),
        namegen=add_url_to_name,
    )
}
```